# How to find the list of fields which are using generator in firebird table?

Tags: sql, firebird

How can I select the field names from firebird table which are using generator for auto increment.

Comment: What does the table look like? What does your script look like currently? What have you tried unsuccessfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Currently (as of Firebird 2.5) there is no auto increment fields in the Firebird, you have to mimic them yourself with trigger. And thus there is no metadata you could use to associate the sequence (aka generator) and an field.

Comment: Even with the `autoincrement` proposed for Firebird 3.0, it will only be syntactic sugar for creating the necessary sequence and trigger

Comment: I want to convert the Firebird table into MSSQL table. Instead of that task i need to identify the generator used fields for covert it into identity field in MSSQL table.

Comment: You have to inspect the DDL of the Firebird database to check out how and where each generator is used. If there is a good naming conversation in use (ie table Foo uses generator named genFoo for the PK) then you might be able to automate it, but otherwise it is a manual process.

Answer (score 0):

Well OK, this is HACKY and not very efficient, but its something that is pretty damned close.

This will return the FIRST identity field for Fields using a generator for each table. BUT this does assume that your triggers look something like

```
  NEW.My_ID = GEN_ID(My_ID_Generator,1)
```

It also works if you have a null check (thats why you need a second nested select)

```
  If ((NEW.MY_ID) is NULL) then NEW.My_ID...
```

You could probably make it a stored proc or view.

```
Select P.TableName,
       CASE WHEN position('NEW.' in P.Body)>0 THEN
            substring(P.Body from
              (position('NEW.' in P.Body)+4)
            )
            ELSE p.Body
       END As IdentityName  
FROM
  (
  SELECT
      B.TableName,
      substring(B.Body from (position('NEW.' in B.Body)+4) for
         position('=GEN_ID' in B.Body)-(position('NEW.' in B.Body)+4)
      ) as Body
  FROM
     (
      SELECT RDB$RELATION_NAME AS TableName,
             UPPER(
               replace (
                 replace(
                   replace(
                      replace(t.RDB$TRIGGER_SOURCE,' ',''), ascii_char(13), ''
                   ), ascii_char(10), ''
                 ), ascii_char(9), ''
               )
             ) as Body
        FROM RDB$TRIGGERS t
        WHERE ((rdb$SYSTEM_FLAG IS NULL) or (t.rdb$SYSTEM_FLAG=0)) AND
             (RDB$TRIGGER_TYPE=1) and
             ((RDB$TRIGGER_INACTIVE = 0) OR (RDB$TRIGGER_INACTIVE IS NULL) ) and
             (( RDB$TRIGGER_SOURCE like '%GEN_ID%') and (RDB$TRIGGER_SOURCE like '%NEW.%'))
      ) B
) P
```

The Result looks like this:

```
 TABLENAME  IDENTITYNAME 
 ---------  ----------- 
 My_Table   My_ID
```